# How to fix health check on gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to setup a website for this I created a vm instance and setup the `gcp load balancer` to the `instance group`. Setup the `Cloud DNS` and finally `reserved the static ip` and updated the dns records. However I get a `502` My gcp `health check` fails even though the instance is running. the  Below are my settings

[image: Load Balancer configuration]

[image: Health Check Configuration]

[image: External IP Config]
[image: DNS Config]

[image: Firewall setting]

[image: All firewall rules]

Comment: Did you check [firewall](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#fw-rule)?

Comment: edited the question with all the firewall rules configured

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding the network tag to my vm. Even though all the firewall rules were in place I needed to add the `allow-firewall-check` tag to my vm instance.